# Developing python GUI applications on chromebook

Tags: python, user-interface, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I know that you can use **chromebook** for development, working with cloud ide services like [Cloud9](https://c9.io/), [CodeEnvy](https://codenvy.com/), [Koding](https://koding.com/), [Nitrous](https://www.nitrous.io/) etc.

And while this is truly great, I am working mostly with UI, specifically [python Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). As I've learnt, you cannot use GUI apps on any known cloud services even though you can `sudo apt-get install python-tk` in **Nitrous** workspace for example.

Maybe I was not able to find such cloud ide service which allows you to run python GUI applications. 
Can you tell is it currently possible at all without relying on such hacks as **[crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)**?

Comment: you're shooting yourself in the foot. Why don't you just buy a normal computer and go on with your coding?

Comment: Lightweight (no more than 1.5kg), fanless, SSD, non Atom based with a quality screen? Can you show me such laptop available on the market currently?

Comment: MacBook Air is your answer. Or Dell XPS.

Comment: What's wrong with Atom CPUs? I have an Atom-based mini-PC that's less than 1kg, fanless, SSD, and includes a nice 1920x1200 display, and it's perfectly fine for Python development. It dual-boots Android and Windows 10.

Comment: All for ~$300? 
I have my own reasons to buy chromebook and I am looking to solve a minor issue of running GUI apps on it without using **crouton**.

Comment: You can install Python using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), although you will need to enable developer mode for this. For more information see [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64201789).

Comment: I took my Ubuntu Python Tkinter Music Player and it ran on Chromebook ChromeOS Linux Beta without a problem other than one or two lines of code requiring  `if` then `else` statements.